# I need to create a new dataframe as below in pysaprk from given input dataset

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

persons who has same salary should come in same record and their names should be separated by ",".

input Dataset :

[image]

Expected Dataset

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this as below -

Apply a `groupBy` on `Salary` and use - [collect_list](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.collect_list.html) to club all the `Name` inside an `ArrayType()`

Further you can choose to convert it to a StringType using - [concat_ws](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.concat_ws.html)

#### Data Preparation

```
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO("""Name,Salary
                abc,100000
                bcd,20000
                def,100000
                pqr,20000
                xyz,30000
        """)
    ,delimiter=','
).applymap(lambda x: str(x).strip())

sparkDF = sql.createDataFrame(df)

sparkDF.groupby("Salary").agg(F.collect_list(F.col("Name")).alias('Name')).show(truncate=False)

+------+----------+
|Salary|Name      |
+------+----------+
|100000|[abc, def]|
|20000 |[bcd, pqr]|
|30000 |[xyz]     |
+------+----------+
```

#### Concat WS

```
sparkDF.groupby("Salary").agg(F.concat_ws(",",F.collect_list(F.col("Name"))).alias('Name')).show(truncate=False)

+------+-------+
|Salary|Name   |
+------+-------+
|100000|abc,def|
|20000 |bcd,pqr|
|30000 |xyz    |
+------+-------+
```